# can Excel's autofitColumns javascript API autofit the width according to range's content rather than column's content?

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

[doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.rangeformat?view=excel-js-preview#autofitcolumns--) says autofits Changes the width of the columns of the current range to achieve the best fit, based on the current data in the columns. So it's based on the data in the columns.

Now I have an example: input 'aaaaaaaaaaaaa' in A1 and 'aaa' in A2, and I execute `ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet().getRange("A2").format.autofitColumns();` but it autofits according to the A1's content rather than A2's, but what I want is the later one, is there any way to achieve this please?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I can repro this issue, I think our behavior API aligned with when double click the resizable button in column, it will resize according to the content of the whole column.

A bug(#3984867) was created to track this issue, Team is investigation on it.

[image: A Column sizeable icon],